# Best way to parse this response into an associative array?

Tags: php

Below is the response I'm getting after posting to an API.... I don't think parse_url is going to cut it. Are there any built in PHP functions or better ways to turn this into an array? This is the output of var_dump

```
sting(163) "response=3&responsetext=Duplicate transaction REFID:115545335&authcode=&transactionid=&avsresponse=&cvvresponse=&orderid=&type=auth&response_code=300&processor_id="
```

Comment: Looking for [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) with the optional `$arr` parameter.

> Parses str as if it were the query string passed via a URL

Comment: Tried that, when I do $parsedQuery = parse_str($checkAuth); var_dump($parsedQuery);  I get NULL for the output

Comment: @mprototype: Look at the docs a little closer, it doesn't return an object, it automatically places the result within your scope. If you want to assign it to a variable, use the second argument.

Comment: @mprototype see the manual page: You need to specify the output array. (This is admittedly silly and inconsistent with the rest of the `parse_` functions, but what are you going to do.) @Brad I made it CW because I know for a fact this is a triplicate or quadruplicate, but I'm too lazy to search

Comment: NM, I needed to add the second parameter for parse_str to work. Think I got it, thanks!

Comment: @Pekka: Need better SEO on these entries then. ;p

Comment: @Brad yeah, absolutely! Being able to search *in answers* would be the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [parse_str.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

It turns a query string into an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

I propose :

```
$elements = explode('&', $input);
$data = array();
foreach($elements as $e) {
    $d = explode('=', $e);
    $data[$d[0]] = isset($d[1]) ? $d[1] : '';
}
```

But maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Not going to down vote, but [there does exist a better way](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

Comment: Since the OP said that parse_url don't work, I imagined parse_str won't work either, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: parse_url just compartmentalizes the segments (breaks out that the string is, in fact, a bunch of GET variables. S/he wants those variables parsed in to what PHP typicaly does with an incoming URL--which is where `parse_str` comes in to play.